# join two dataframes based on multiple criteria

Tags: pandas, dataframe, merge

I have a dataframe which is as follows

```
df1 = 
month port volume
1     usa   5
2     usa   6
3     usa   5
1     mex   2
2     mex   2
3     mex   2

df2 = 
date  month  port 
1     1      usa
2     1      usa
3     1      usa
1     2      usa
2     2      usa
3     2      usa
1     1      mex
2     1      mex
3     1      mex
1     2      mex
2     2      mex
3     2      mex
```

I would now like to add the 'volume' column associated with df1 for each month to df2 using "merge".

how do I do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df=df1.merge(df2,on=['month','port'],how='right')
```